# Pass data from generator in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I need to feed a neural network model with data read from a generator. For instance, consider this:

```
import numpy as np
def gener():
    for i in range(100):
        yield np.random.sample((28,28))
```

I am trying to use this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gener,output_types=tf.float32)
train_labels = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=100)
```

When creating a first model layer and fitting, say like this:

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.models import Sequential
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28,1,)))
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x=train_data,y=labels_train, epochs=7, verbose=1
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'FlatMapDataset' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

What am I missing ? What can I do to fit data from a generator to my model ?

Answer (score 0):

When using generators each item should be a pair of the input data and the label. Like this:

```
def gener():
    for i in range(100):
        yield (np.random.sample((28, 28, 1)),
               tf.one_hot(np.random.randint(0, 10), 10))
```

This corresponds to your `train_data` and `train_labels` which I have also one-hot encoded for you.

To create a dataset from it you need to explicitly declare the types that are involved:

```
train_ds = Dataset.from_generator(gener,
                                  (tf.float32, tf.int32),
                                  (tf.TensorShape([28, 28, 1]),
                                  tf.TensorShape([10])))
```

Then you need to manually create mini-batches:

```
train_ds = train_ds.batch(4)
```

Then you need to call it like this:

```
model.fit(x = train_ds, epochs = 7, verbose = 1)
```

I.e don't specify the y parameter.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. I am unfortunately getting an error of the same type: AttributeError: 'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'ndim' . Any other ideas ?

Comment: I actually checked your exact code and got the error . What tf version are you using ? I am on 2.1.0

Comment: 2.2.0. But that is not relevant here. If you correctly implement the code I gave you it will work.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Vih-CkVsZy2HL2wa-A7BQHa4GEuN36ct?usp=sharing